# Reactjs pass variable to function from another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Request.js**

```
export default class Request extends React.Component {
getForm(e) {
  let v = validator(document.getElementById('myinput')); // here is should call function from another class
}
render(){
  return(
      <form onSubmit={this.getForm.bind(this)}>
        <RequestValidator/> // here is I called second class
        <Input id="myinput" value="65"/>
      </form>
    }
  }
}
```

**RequestValidator.js**

```
export default class RequestValidator extends React.Component {
  validator = (e) => { // here is the target function
    console.log(e.value);
  }
}
```

What I want to do is, pass a variable (`#myinput` value) from `Request` compontent class to a function (`validator`) in another compontent class (`RequestValidator`).

What I have done so far is above codes, but I got error:

> 'validator' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Please indent your code, it looks very messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `ref`. You create one in your parent component:

```
class Request extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.requestValidatorRef = React.createRef();
    }
```

then you pass it to the child component:

```
<RequestValidator ref={this.requestValidatorRef} />
```

at this point you should be able to call your method like this:

```
getForm(e) {
  this.requestValidatorRef.current.validator(e) // ...
}
```

Comment: And it return: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined`

Comment: you may need to share your attempt. current can be undefined, because it is set later

Comment: Everything is right. but need one change to work. Just remove .current from this.requestValidatorRef.current.validator(e)

Comment: No, it is my mistake, it call function, but my code inside the function return nothing, so this problem solved, thanks

Comment: By the way document.getElementById('myinput') is not react syntax. react using ref for this.

Comment: Nice answer :)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameter to another class in reactjs you should use props. Also variable in requestvalidator class have to use prop name. But in your case RequestValidator and Input components are different.
In main component class call like this:

```
  <UserInput
         titles={this.state.titles}
    />
```

In UserInput component use this prop like this:

```
class UserInput extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log(" titles from main class:", this.props.titles);
      }
}
```